# Why does my IronPython Console do this?

Tags: python, ironpython

I use the IronPython Console when I feel like programming, but it does some wacky stuff. For example:

```
If a=("X")
```

it says "Unexpected token '=.'
Or this:

```
If a is ("X"):
    print ("Y")
else:
    print ("Z")
```

But it should end after that, it still puts in "...". Why?

Answer (score 9):

First question:

```
if a=("X"):
```

is not valid Python code. You probably meant:

```
if a == ("X"):
```

For the second one, the REPL (read-eval-print loop - the shell) doesn't know when you're going to end a block until it sees an empty line. For example:

```
>>> if a == "X":
...     print "Y"
... else:
...     print "Z"
...
```

You might still want to enter another statement on the next line. If you leave it blank, the REPL knows that you're done that block and want to start a new one. This is a side-effect of Python's significant whitespace.

Comment: I think the REPL part isn't very clear for a beginner, maybe you could clarify that part of your answer a bit.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop for a description of REPL

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if x==('x'):
    print('x')
```

This is because the `=` is an assignment. `==` is a comparison.